# Составить правильный FormData запрос

Tags: javascript, node.js, formdata, multer

Отправляя запрос на сервер через postman все работает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При попытке отправить такой же запрос через клиент, `req.body` на сервере равен пустому объекту:

```js
const img = ev.target.files[0];
const body = new FormData();
body.append('image', img);
body.append('user', localStorage.getItem('user'));
const data = await (await fetch(`${root}/api/upload/profile`, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data;'
  },
  body
})).json();
```

Вот роут `/profile`:

```js
router.post('/profile',
    cors(corsOptions),
    async(req, res) => {
        upload(req, res, async err => {
            try {
                console.log(req.body) // {}
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err.stack)
            }
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: в постмане установлено 8 заголовков. В коде - всего один

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил проблему просто передавая в `headers` пустой объект:

```js
const img = ev.target.files[0];
const body = new FormData();
body.append('image', img);
body.append('user', localStorage.getItem('user'));
const data = await (await fetch(`${root}/api/upload/profile`, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {},
  body
})).json();
```

Comment: пустой объект можно вообще не передавать.

Comment: возможно проблема была в отсутствии указания для boundaries для form-data в заголовке